# Identifying mutations between haplotypes using haploNet (pegas) in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, dna-sequence, phylogeny

I think this might be an easy question, but I could not solve it after reading the pegas documentation. I want to plot an haplotype network using a FASTA file and identify which mutations are separatting the distinct haplotypes.

**Example:**

```
fa <- read.FASTA("example.fa")
haps <- haplotype(fa)
haps50 <- subset(haps, minfreq = 50)
(network <- haploNet(haps50))

plot(network, size = attr(network, "freq"),show.mutation=1,labels=T)
```

[image]

How can I identify the position of the mutation in my FASTA file that is separating for example haplotype `XX` from `V`?

**Extra question:**
Would it be also possible to know for example, what is the haplotype sequence of one of the haplotypes? For example haplotype `V`, which is quite frequent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pegas` package contains a function `diffHaplo`, which specifies differences between haplotypes.

```
diffHaplo(haps50, a = "XX", b = "V")
```

To extract the DNA sequence of the frequent haplotype `V`, the indexes in the object of class `haplotype` will identify, which DNA sequence contains the haplotype.

```
# haplotype index from its name
i <- which(attr(haps50, "dimnames")[[1]] == "V")
# index of the first sequence with the haplotype
s <- attr(haps50, "index")[[i]][1]
```

The respective sequence can then be identified in the alignment `fa` to save or print on screen.

```
write.dna(fa[s], file = "hapV.fas", format = "fasta", nbcol = -1, colsep = "")
paste(unlist(as.character(fa[s])), collapse = "")
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. `fa[s]` is printing only one base instead of the whole sequence.

Comment: Is `fa` class `DNAbin`?

Comment: Yes, it is class `DNAbin`.

Comment: Then, I need to see the data to be able to fix the problem.